# My Inteliij IDEA jdk settings are totally messed up, can anyone help me?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Okay, because I was running out of space I uninstalled many programs(including java 8 development kit), then I reinstalled the jdk files. So, when I reopened inteliij is not working. All java tokens like `String` and `System` and all java tokens  are showing `cannot resolve symbol 'String'(when mouse is hovered to String)`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfAxp.png)

and screenshot of my run tab.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJYUv.png)

I know, this question is way similar to some question in this community.
But, those answers are not solving mine. How to fix?

Comment: Is the project SDK set? Did you point to the newest folder (change JAVA_HOME variable?)

Comment: How to do it?, I was not asked for it till now.

Comment: Literally just google for "set JAVA_HOME". You need to tell your IntelliJ where to find the jdk :)

Comment: Yeah the problem was because I installed it in `compatible mode on`. Anyways thanks for those `JAVA_HOME`, I don't anymore need to set path in `cmd` :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the instructions in the IntelliJ documentation below and add SDK for your project. This will resolve all your SDK related issues.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/sdks.html

Comment: Yes even I have those same configurations, but still it's not working!, as same as of that picture I have 20 files in classpath tab that are like this`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk 1.8.0_131\jre\lib\"something".jar`

Comment: with given info, i suggest you can try couple of things 1. try removing and adding the SDK in intellij 2. uninstall and reinstall JDK on your machine

Comment: Okay, the problem is solved, as I said due to low disk space I uninstalled jdk, and because 1.8.0_131 is bit unstable I reinstalled with windows compatibility mode and I think that cause all those problem, because this time I let it to be installed normally and everything is Okay now